# How can threads ID be equal?

Tags: pthreads

I'm currently learning about operating systems and concurrency and I'm tasked with using pthreads in c.

After trying to understand and use pthreads, there's a couple of things that I don't quite understand.

If I create two seperate pthreads (two processes, to my understanding), how can the two threads be equal (pthread_equal)? Or what does it mean by this?

Thanks!

Comment: A thread is not a process. A thread is task unit in a process assigned to do  work.

Comment: so when checking if two threads are equal, is that checking whether they are combined within the same process?

Comment: Read this: https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_equal

Comment: Okay, so if two threads have an equal ID, does that not mean it's the same thread? how does it distinguish between the two? Thanks for replying by the way, I don't intend asking rubbish questions, just as long as I learn something from it.

Comment: Yes, if the return value of `thread_equal` is true, then it is the same thread. Note[1]: In a multithreaded process, all threads have the same PID, but each one has a unique TID (thread ID).
Note[2]: thread ID is unique within the creating process, so two threads in different processes might have the same ID.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

> If I create two seperate pthreads (two processes, to my understanding), ..

Nope. Threads are not processes. (Threads may be implemented using processes under the hood - but it's still a thread as far as user programs are concerned and should treat them as such).

> how can the two threads be equal (pthread_equal)? Or what does it mean by this?

It means it's *same* thread and is reported by `pthread_equal()` which compares whether given thread IDs (`pthread_t`) are equal.
A direct comparsion using `==` isn't possible because `pthread_t` is an opaque type and the only way to compare thread IDs is to use `pthread_equal()` API.

By the way, two threads in *different* processes may have the same ID (`pthread_t`).